# How to create React elements in an array (with props) and then render them by simply mapping over that array?

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering if there is a way to create elements in an array and then simply render them, if that is possible it will simplify my code a bit.

Right now I am defining sections for a page in one file, then that gets sent to another and so on, so at the moment it looks like this

```
const heroSectionProps = { ... }

const pageLayout = {
  sections: [{name: "Hero", props: heroSectionProps}]
}
```

and later when rendering the page I am doing the following:

```
import { Hero } from "~/sections"

const section = {
  Hero: Hero
}

export const Page = ({ sections, ...props }) => {

  return sections.map(({ name, props }) => { 
    const Section = section[name];

    return <Section {...props} />
  })
}
```

And that works just fine, now the question is, is it possible to somehow move to a syntax that would look more like this:

```
import { Hero } from "~/sections"

const heroSectionProps = { ... }

const pageLayout = {
  sections: [Hero(heroSectionProps)]
}
```

and then in page:

```
export const Page = ({ sections, ...props }) => {

  return sections.map(Section => (<Section />))
}
```

So the idea is to already have the components created within the layout object and then to simply pass them to the page to directly render them. Of course, doing it the above way, I got an error:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a 
string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <HeroContainer />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal 
instead of a component?
```

And other similar about invalid type.

So is that even possible, worth it and how?

Comment: I don't know if one could create an array of function like what you're trying to achieve. But an array of object like your working current logics definitely will work. Maybe you could just simplified it to `sections: [{ section: Hero(heroSectionProps) }]`. Don't know whether it will work tho. Cause this will invoke the function right away. Never done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render an array, so long as it's filled with renderable values (strings, numbers, elements and components). So, say we have an array of components:

```
import Hero from '../Hero';

const componentsArray = [<p>Hello world!</p>, <div><img src="images/flower.png" /></div>, <Hero {...heroSectionProps} />];
```

You can instantly render it:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  //... 

  return componentsArray;
};
```